# PowerPoint: Proceed to next slide on click, regardless of the ongoing animations in the current slide

Tags: animation, microsoft-powerpoint, presentation-design

**What I currently have can be seen in this video:**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxYxBmy8_iA3akhNdzBhOGJCSXc/view?usp=sharing

In the video you can see that I need to click twice in order to get to the second slide (white background): once to end the ongoing animation and a second time to transition to the next slide.

The animation setup can be seen here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxYxBmy8_iA3QmNNejhKUkRtd3c/view?usp=sharing

I have an entrance "fly-in" animation for both texts. After that I have a path animation for each of them. These path animations start after the previous and last 16 seconds.

**What I want to have:**

I'd like to be able to transition to the second slide with one singe mouse click, regardless of the state of the text animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a hyperlink, on some element, to the next slide to click it directly.

Comment: This is an ugly hack that I have no trouble using, whatsoever. The problem is that PowerPoint probably has some sort of "cursor activity detection" logic built in. Check out this video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxYxBmy8_iA3WWpIak9abHJiOUk
I've put a transparent rectangle over the whole slide, that has a hyperlink to the next slide. Observe how the first run I don't get the results I need, because I didn't shake the mouse cursor before clicking. The second run gives me the desired result, but I am forced to first do some serious motion before I can click the hyperlink.

Comment: Actually, this behavior is inconsistent. Here's another video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxYxBmy8_iA3Qi1FaG9NaEtaaEU
Here, after the first hyperlink is followed successfully, the second one doesn't need the "mouse shake" in order to work. Thanks for the answer! I'm totally fine with this. I'll wait for several days before accepting it, should any other solutions appear.

Comment: Three months later this is still the only solution. Thanks, Rafael!